# Decide whether or not there exists $f(f(x))=5x-\lfloor 5x\rfloor$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Decide whether or not there exists  $f;[0,1)\to [0,1)$ such 
>   $$f(f(x))=5x-\lfloor 5x\rfloor=\{5x\}$$

Today I suddenly thought of an interesting question, but I have not found any function of symbolic conditions so far.

Comment: What is this interesting question you thought of??? Are you referring to the body of the post? If so, it is indeed an interesting question to ask!

Comment: sorry,this question is creat by me @Bre

Comment: I would guess there are such functions, but I'm more hesitant to claim they're continuous

Comment: I'm assuming the function must be surjective?  Just think if the function could be constant :)

Comment: Well for $x < \frac 15$ let $f(x) = \sqrt 5*x$.  For $\frac 15 \le x<\frac 25$ let $f(x) = \sqrt{5}x - \frac 1{\sqrt 5}$ and for $\frac k5\le x < \frac {k+1}5$ let $f(x) = \sqrt{5}x - \frac 4{\sqrt 5}$.  It's too late for me to check if that works, but I think it does.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen If $f$ were continuous, then $f\circ f$ would be as well. But $\{5x\}$ is not continuous on $[0,1)$. So $f$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: @alex.jordan nice argument! I'm glad to hear my intuition that the function couldn't be continuous was correct :)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Since $\{5x\}$ is piecewise continuous, one might wonder if $f$ could be as well. Thinking about the answer by Piquito makes me suspect $f$ could not be piecewise continuous, but perhaps Piquito's approach could be refined into a limit of piecewise continuous functions. What I'm trying to say is, replace "continuous" with "piecewise continuous" in your comment and I'm right there with you.

Comment: @alex.jordan I would suspect that there is no piecewise continuous $f$ satisfying this; the main issue is that the jump discontinuities of $f\circ f$ all have to have height $1$, which makes it extremely difficult (impossible?) for $f$ to have jump discontinuities of height other than $1$. However, if $f$ has only jump discontinuities of height $1$, then $f$ is basically a continuous map $S^1\rightarrow S^1$, where we identify the circle $S^1$ with $[0,1)$ in the obvious way. The action of $\{5x\}$ on homotopy on $S^1$ is not square, so there can be no square root $f$ continuous on $S^1$.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is such a function. (But I'm going to use the Axiom of Choice to show that, so I don't have any easy formula to offer - but I'm also going to use a general method that solves other problems too)

An easy way to see this is to throw out all the structure that is irrelevant to whether or not a functional square root exists. In particular, let us make the following definitions (which are not a standard definition or names):

> A **system** is a pair $(S,f)$, where $S$ is a set and $f:S\rightarrow S$ is a function.
>
> A system is **square** if it is of the form $(S,f\circ f)$, where $f:S\rightarrow S$ is a function.
>
> Two systems $(S,f)$ and $(T,g)$ are **isomorphic** if there exists a bijection $\pi:S\rightarrow T$ such that $\pi\circ f = g\circ \pi$.
>
> If we have two systems $(S,f)$ and $(T,g)$ with disjoint domains $S$ and $T$, we can define their union $(S,f)\cup (T,g)$ as a pair $(S\cup T,f\cup g)$, where $f\cup g$ is the function taking the values of $f$ in the component of $S$ and the values of $g$ in the component of $T$. Arbitrary unions can be defined similarly.

These definitions tell us to think about functions $S\rightarrow S$ as directed graphs with vertices $S$ and an edge $(x,f(x))$ for every $x\in S$ and to consider isomorphisms of those graphs. Here four examples, showing this graph for some functions with $S=\{0,1,2\}$, namely $f(x)=\max(x-1,0)$ and $f(x)=\min(x+1,2)$ and $f(x)=2$ and $f(x)=x+1\text{ mod }3$:

[image: Four directed graphs corresponding to the functions]

Note that the first two are basically mirror images of one another. The notion of isomorphism captures how these functions have the same structure, whereas the other two functions are different.

Now, we can show a lemma:

> Let $(S,f)$ and $(T,g)$ be isomorphic by some map $\pi:S\rightarrow T$. Assume $S$ and $T$ are disjoint. Then, $(S,f)\cup (T,g)$ is square.

This is because we can define $h:S\cup T\rightarrow S\cup T$: $$h(x)=\begin{cases}\pi(f(x)) & \text{if }x\in S\\
\pi^{-1}(x) & \text{if }x\in T
\end{cases}.$$
Then, for $x\in S$, we have that $$h(h(x))=h(\pi(f(x))=\pi^{-1}(\pi(f(x))=f(x).$$ For $x\in T$ we have $$h(h(x))=h(h(x))=h(\pi^{-1}(x))=\pi(f(\pi^{-1}(x)))=g(\pi(\pi^{-1}(x)))=g(x).$$ Thus, $h$ is a functional square root of $f\cup g$.

Pictorally, we can do an example. We could take a pair of isomorphic functions like the following, where the isomorphism is shown:

[image: A pair of isomorphic directed graphs]

Then, we essentially weave back and forth between the isomorphic parts, in such a way that we take a step "forwards" each time. The result is a functional square root that looks like the following:
[image: Functional square root of union of isomorphic systems]

> Let $\{(S_i,f_i\circ f_i)\}_{i\in I}$ be a collection of square systems with the $S_i$ pairwise disjoint. Then, $\bigcup_{i\in I}(S_i,f_i\circ f_i)$ is square.

This follows by noting that the functional square root of this system is $\bigcup( S_i,f_i)$.

Now, we can apply this to our given function $f(x)=5x-\lfloor 5x\rfloor$ by writing $f$ as the union of other functions. In particular, we define the following:

> A **component** of a system $(S,f)$ is a set of the following form, for some $x\in S$: $$\langle x\rangle=\{y\in S:f^n(y)=f^m(x)\text{ for some }n,m\}.$$

These are exactly the components of the underlying directed graph. A system is always the union of its restrictions to each component. Moreover, each component is a directed graph with either zero or one directed cycles.

Now, we can finish by considering what the components of the given $f$ are. Note that every point in $[0,1)$ has exactly $5$ preimages under $f$. First, there are uncountably many components of the form $\langle x\rangle$ for irrational $x$, and none of these may contain a cycle, since $x,\,f(x),\,f^2(x),\ldots$ is not eventually periodic for irrational $x$. These components all consists of isomorphic systems corresponding to infinite bidirectional trees where every vertex has $5$ predecessors. We may use the axiom of choice to pair them up, and take the square root of every pair.

Then, for rational $x$, the component $\langle x\rangle$ must have a cycle, since $f$ never increases the denominator of a value. The component must therefore consist of an $n$-cycle, where each element of the cycle has $4$ preimages outside of the cycle, then everything outside of the cycle has $5$ preimages. The isomorphism class of this component only depends on $n$. Example components of this form are shown below:
[image]

Now, to finish, we just show that there are an even number of components with an $n$-cycle, since then we can pair these up and take their square root individually, then piece all the pairs back together to get a functional square root of the whole thing.

To see this, note that there are $5^n-1$ elements $x$ satisfying $f^n(x)=x$ - these are just those numbers of the form $\frac{c}{5^n-1}$ for $0\leq c < 5^{n}-1$. Then, we can use the Mobius inversion formula to get that there are
$$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d/n)(5^d-1)$$
elements that are members of an $n$-cycle (and no smaller cycle), where $\mu(x)$ is the Mobius function, equalling $0$ if $x$ is not square-free, otherwise equalling $1$ if $x$ is a product of an even number of primes and $-1$ if it is a product of an odd number of primes.

The number of $n$ cycles is just this quantity over $n$, thus we can do our pairing argument exactly if $2n$ divides $\sum_{d|n}\mu(d/n)(5^d-1)$ for all $n$. Note that, except for $n=1$, this sum can also be written as $\sum_{d|n}\mu(d/n)\cdot 5^d$, since the constant terms will cancel.

Showing this final step is basically an exercise in number theory. If you look mod each prime power and group the given sum by pairs of the form $\{n/d,n/(pd)\}$ where $p$ does not divide $d$, the result falls out fairly easily by noting the exponent of the multiplicative group mod $p^n$. Then, we can repeat this trick on mod powers of $2$, noting that the multiplicative group mod $2^n$ only has exponent $2^{n-2}$ for $n\geq 2$, which let us get the result we want.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, this argument shows that the map $g:[0,1)\rightarrow [0,1)$ given by $g(x)=\{cx\}$ where $\{\cdot\}$ is the fractional part operator and $c\in \mathbb N$ has a functional square root for all odd $c$. One can show this is impossible for $c=2$, but other even numbers seem hard to handle.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it it exists as the following example shows.The function $\{5x\}$ in the interval $[0,1)$ is explicitly defined by
$$\begin{equation}\{5x\}=\begin{cases}5x\space \text{ for }0\le x\lt 0.2\\5x-1\space \text{ for }0.2\le x\lt 0.4\\5x-2\space \text{ for }0.4\le x\lt 0.6\\{5x-3}\space \text{ for }0.6\le x\lt 0.8\\5x-4\space \text{ for }0.8\le x\lt 1\end{cases}\end{equation}$$ so we can calculate an example of $f(x)=\sqrt5\space x+b$ such that $f(f(x))$ coincides with the funcion above. Calculation gives

$$\begin{equation}f(x)=\begin{cases} \sqrt 5\space x\quad\text{ for }0\le x\lt 0.2\\\\\sqrt 5\space x-\dfrac{\sqrt5-1}{4} \text{ for }0.2\le x\lt 0.4\\\\\sqrt 5\space x-\dfrac{(\sqrt5-1)}{2}\space \text{ for }0.4\le x\lt 0.6\\\\\sqrt 5\space x-\dfrac{3(\sqrt5-1)}{4}\space \text{ for }0.6\le x\lt 0.8\\\\\sqrt 5\space x-(\sqrt5-1)\space \text{ for }0.8\le x\lt 1\end{cases}\end{equation}$$ It follows
 $$\color{red}{f(f(x))=\{5x\}}$$ as it is easy to verify.

Comment: @Piquito $f(f(0.2))≠0$.

Comment: $$f(f(x))=f(\sqrt5\space x-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4})=\sqrt5\left(\sqrt5\space x-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}\right)-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}=5x-1$$ and $5x-1=5x-2=5x-3=5x-4=0$ as for $\{x\}$ for the values $0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8$.

Comment: @Piquito I think your calculation is relying on the hope that if $0.2\leq x < 0.4$ then $0.2 \leq f(x) < 0.4$, so that you will end up applying the same segment of $f$ twice - in which case you *would* get the desired result. However, this is not so - the calculation for $f(f(x))$ could fall under a different case than the calculation for $f(x)$, in which case this will fail. While $\sqrt{5}x-\frac{k(\sqrt{5}-1)}4$ is a functional square root of $5x-k$ as a map $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$, compositing the functions together as done here does not preserve that except near $k/4$.

Comment: As explained by Milo Brandt, this answer is wrong. Consider the case $x=0.1$. Then $x\in [0,0.2)$ and consequently $f(x)=\sqrt5 x\approx 0.223607$. Hence $f(x)\in[0.2,0.4)$ and
$$f(f(x))=\sqrt{5}f(x)-(\sqrt5-1)/4=5x-(\sqrt5-1)/4\neq0.5=\{5\cdot 0.1\}.$$

Comment: But, whoever flagged this as NOT AN ANSWER should review the SE definitions a bit. This is obviously a good faith attempt at an answer, so THAT FLAG DOES NOT APPLY! The answer is wrong, but that is irrelevant for the purposes of the NAA-flag. You need to use other measures.

Comment: @Milo Brandt: I want to thank Jyrki Lahtonen and Milo Brandt very much for their comments that have made me see that, in fact, I made a mistake. But I clarify that I'm not asking anyone upvote but it seems pretty foolish to put sportingly  (or perhaps with bad intention) downvotes (plural) to an attempt to give an effort and whose error could go unnoticed.

Comment: @Milo Brandt: I want to add that (although you do not believe me) I put you an upvote and think please that the downvotes I received would look like I had put you a downvote because the OP’s tags does not include set theory or formal logic. Excuse me the bad English.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: See please the comments to Milo Brandt. Thank you very much.